# Private Ethereum Chain and Web3 js API

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, private

I've developed my own private chain for testnet using geth and CLique and i have some issues with web3.js environment. I starts my nodes using the console parameter in order to get to the Web3 console but now i discovered that some functions doesn't work. For example, i call the contract using

```
myContract.at("addressofminedcontract").foo
```

but if, following the doc i use

```
new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])
```

it doesn't work, returning

`"Contract is not a function"`.

Or again, if i try to call `myContract.options` i get an error back.The same happens for example with the  `web3.eth.getPastLogs(options [, callback])`

Anyway, it looks like my web3 is not complete or something is missing. How can i solve that? Since geth encapsulates a console environment i thought it was enough, am i missing something?

Thanks guys

Comment: This is a problem of web3 version, not of geth or private chain

Answer (score 0):

Change the web3 version by running following command in the project directory:

```
npm install web3@0.20
```

The latest web3 which is 1.0 has many changes. And most of the sources you find for web3 have explained according to the old version.

Comment: thank you. In which folder i have to run it? The project folder containing nodes or inside nodes folders instead (where the geth folder is) ?

Comment: In your project folder. Where there is `contracts` directory. I am assuming  you are using truffle to build the project. If it's otherwise, let me know.

Comment: No i'm not using truffle. I deploy in the old fashion using web3deploy code plus the json interface (abi) for  calling the smart cotract

Comment: Then I guess you might be using a globally installed web3. For that you can change its version by `npm install -g web3@0.20`